# Frontend rest api call not redirect to Auth0 login because CORS error

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security, auth0

I am new at Auth0 and using react for front-end and spring boot for back-end. What I want to do that calling rest api for redirecting auth0 login page. But when I call `adminLogin` api redirection to auth0 login not happen. Chrome console says:

[image]

I am confused at this point. Button calls rest and debugger goes controller but because of I use at frontend `localhost:3000` and at backend `localhost:8080` it cannot redirect auth0 login.
Here is my controller:

```
    @ResponseBody
    public void login(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws IOException {
        String redirectUrl = "http://localhost:8080/adminLogin";
        String authorizeUrl = authenticationController.buildAuthorizeUrl(request, response, redirectUrl)
                .withScope("openid email")
                .build();
        response.sendRedirect(authorizeUrl);
    }
```

and security config:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Value(value = "${com.auth0.domain}")
    private String domain;

    @Value(value = "${com.auth0.clientId}")
    private String clientId;

    @Value(value = "${com.auth0.clientSecret}")
    private String clientSecret;

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.csrf().disable();
        http
                .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/adminLogin", "/admins", "/").permitAll()
                .anyRequest().authenticated()
                .and()
                .formLogin()
                .loginPage("/adminLogin");
    }

    @Bean
    public AuthenticationController authenticationController() throws UnsupportedEncodingException {
        JwkProvider jwkProvider = new JwkProviderBuilder(domain).build();
        return AuthenticationController.newBuilder(domain, clientId, clientSecret)
                .withJwkProvider(jwkProvider)
                .build();
    }
}
```

and frontend axios call:

```
loginWithAuth0 =  (e) => {
        axios.get('adminLogin')
            .then(response => {
                const data = response.data
                this.setState({data: data})
            })

    }
```

lastly my callback url in auth0 settings

[image]

Answer (score 0):

In Auth0 Dashbaord application settings, Fill `Allowed Web Origins` field with `http://localhost:3000`